# Merging multiple columns together while keeping each element row-separated?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

Code:

```
DF <- data.frame(lapply(data.frame(Col1 = c("test", "", "test3"),
                               Col2 = c("", "test2", ""),
                               Col3 = c("", "", "test4")), as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

What it outputs:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1  test            
2       test2      
3 test3       test4
```

What I want to do, is create a new column which merges the 3 columns together. I have this following code:

```
DF$Merged <- do.call(paste0, DF[c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")])
```

This outputs the following:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3     Merged
1  test                   test
2       test2            test2
3 test3       test4 test3test4
```

This works somewhat great, as I get a column that I've named "Merged". However, a problem arises in row 3, where the element value is test3 and test4 merged together. I want those two elements to be under the same column (Merged) but not in the same element. An ideal solution would be if R created an extra row and put on of them in there instead, so it ends up like this:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3 Merged
1  test              test1
2       test2        test2
3 test3       test4  test3
4                    test4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `paste` the elements together and then with `separate_rows`, split the rows into 'long' format by splitting at one or more spaces (`\\s+`) before a letter (`(?=[A-Za-z])`) to essentially rule out splitting at any space before a number i.e. 'test 3' or  'test 2'

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  mutate(Merged = trimws(do.call(paste, .))) %>% 
  separate_rows(Merged, sep="\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])")
```

---

If the patterns are unclear, then we create the `sep` while `paste`ing

```
DF %>% 
    mutate(Merged = gsub("^,+|,+$", "", gsub(",{2,}", ",", 
       do.call(paste, c(., list(sep=",")))))) %>% 
    separate_rows(Merged, sep=",\\s*")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! Unfortunately, I noticed that it parses based on space, and not element. So for instance if string words were "test 1", "test 2", etc. with a space inside the string, then it divides the "test" into one row, and the "1" into another row, so basically it splits up the elements based on the spacing.

Would it be possible to replace trimws with another property? I think that might be determining it?

Comment: @Woels Could you please update your example with that kind of an example

Comment: I will update my main question, since the comments offer too few characters.

Comment: @WoeIs  Try `separate_rows(Merged, sep="\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])")`

Comment: That worked, thank you! Could you please explain the     sep="\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])" part for me? :)

Comment: @Woels  here, I am suggesting to split at one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by a capital or lower case letter that essentially rule out the space before the numbers

Comment: Is there not a statement that can be put for sep= where it separates between elements instead? I'm thinking of cases where if an element might have a full name like "Thomas J. Smith" to keep it all in one row?

Comment: It definitely works better. The only thing I'm trying to figure out now is where in the code it separates based on comma. Like if I have a name "Thomas, AE", then it seems to separate Thomas and AE into different rows, that's the only issue left it seems. I'm assuming it's the gsub(",{2,}", ",",  part that does this, correct?

Comment: @Woels  I thought you don't have a comma.  Then, use a `sep` that is unusual

Comment: @Woels Another option is to `gather`, and then `unnest` i.e. `DF %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% gather(key, val, Col1:Col3) %>% filter(val != "") %>% group_by(rn) %>% summarise(Merged = list(val))  %>% left_join(rownames_to_column(DF, 'rn')) %>% unnest %>% select(-rn)`

Comment: The gather and unnest worked flawlessly, thank you! I will have to look into the R tutorial documentation and see how you applied those functions. Thank you so much for the help and for introducing me to new functions in R!