# Duplicating a row based on number of elements filled for that corresponding row

Tags: r, row

I have a data frame that is resembled by the example below:

Code:

```
   DF <- data.frame(lapply(data.frame(Company = c("Company1", "Company2", "Company3", "Company4"),
                                  Col1 = c("test 1", "", "", ""),
                                   Col2 = c("", "test 2", "", "test 3"),
                                   Col3 = c("", "", "", "test 4")), as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and the data frame looks like this:

```
    Company      Col1   Col2   Col3 
1   Company1    test 1                  
2   Company2           test 2           
3   Company3           
4   Company4           test 3  test 4
```

I would like to achieve the following output data frame:

```
    Company      Col   
1   Company1    test 1                  
2   Company2    test 2           
3   Company4    test 3
4   Company4    test 4
```

The output is basically assigning a single available element from columns Col1, Col2 and Col3 for a particular reference column (Company) in the row. If the row has two or more values (like in row number 3), then it should create duplicate rows and assign a single element to it in no particular order.

It is fine to also have a blank against Company 3 in the output (Col) as long as every Company is accounted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have had no luck with keywords for coming up with code to do the above. The closest code has been [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404124/merging-multiple-columns-together-while-keeping-each-element-row-separated) but it doesn't address the task of duplicating a reference column (which is "Company" in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach. Reshape your data from wide to long format and filter for cases were column 'Col' is not `""`.

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  gather('value', 'Col', -Company) %>% 
  filter(Col != "") %>% 
  select(-value)
#   Company    Col
#1 Company1 test 1
#2 Company2 test 2
#3 Company4 test 3
#4 Company4 test 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tidyr:unite` to merge all columns starting with "col" and then split into multiple rows using `unnest`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% unite("col", starts_with("col"), sep=",") %>%
  mutate(col = strsplit(as.character(col), ",")) %>%
  unnest(col) %>% filter(col != "")

#    Company    col
# 1 Company1 test 1
# 2 Company2 test 2
# 3 Company4 test 3
# 4 Company4 test 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R`, option would be to `unlist` the dataset without the 1st column, create a logical index based on blank elements to filter the blank, replicate the first column (to make the lengths same), filter out the blank elements and create a `data.frame`

```
v1 <- unlist(DF[-1], use.names = FALSE)
i1 <- nzchar(v1)
data.frame(Company = rep(DF$Company, 3)[i1], col = v1[i1])
#   Company    col
#1 Company1 test 1
#2 Company2 test 2
#3 Company4 test 3
#4 Company4 test 4
```